# How to document changes to a project

Tags: documentation, java-ee

A company I work with uses a "skeleton" project as base scaffolding for each project they have.
I work on several edits to the skeleton. Some of them are few lines on huge source files. What's a good way to document all the edits I'm making?

Comment: At a minimum, write commit notes when you check-in into the version control.

Answer (score 1):

1. Follow your employer's policies on documenting the edits you make.
2. Follow the policies on documenting the edits you make on any specific projects that have different policies.  Generally, it's possible to do both of these, so you should do both.  There's only a conflict if one policy or the other tells you to not follow the other policy or the one.  In case of a conflict, the project generally wins, within the scope of the project's own files, and the employer generally wins outside of the scope of the project's own files.
3. If neither your employer nor your projects have policies on how you document the edits you make, come up with something that seems reasonable and suggest it.
4. If, by this point, you still don't have policies that direct how you document the edits you make, good luck, and you have my sympathy.  When I was in this situation (company chose to not have a policy), I tracked all of my changes in my own version control repository (because the company also chose to not have one of those) to the best of my ability and looked for other work.  But that's what I did; you are free to choose your own path.